# Can I use google earth or google map static 2D images as background in a Unity android game?

Tags: android, google-maps, unity-game-engine, google-earth

I can´t find nothing about this and google permissions doc are very abstract.

So, can I use google earth or google map  2D static images top-down, without street names or any other info, as background in a google play android game made in Unity?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about legal issues (terms of use), not coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really want to emphasize this, because Google couldn’t make it clearer that attribution is absolutely required. It adds in the “Frequently Asked Questions” that “Without exception, we require attribution when Content is shown. Please do not ask to negotiate this requirement.”5 And it clarifies for Google Earth: “You can personally use an image from the application (for example on your website, on a blog or in a word document) as long as you preserve the copyrights and attributions including the Google logo attribution.

There are other limits spelled out on Google’s permissions page — you can’t create your own map by tracing a Google Map, for example. So anybody who wants to use images from Google Maps or Google Earth should read through the limits carefully.

**But within those limits, Google says, you can use images in reports, presentations, on the web, in a print project. You can even use them in an advertisement.**

About the only place you can’t use them is “in items for resale (i.e., t-shirts, beach towels, shower curtains, mugs).

**In Short** - you can use but don't change map image